# sql show partition based on found record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry I know you want example code but unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how I can implement this functionality or for what I have to search for.

Let's pretend we have this relation:

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║ id  name  quality ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║ 1   Will  4       ║
║ 2   Joe   9       ║
║ 3   Bill  2       ║
║ 4   Max   1       ║
║ 5   Jan   10      ║
║ 6   Susi  5       ║
║ 7   Chris 6       ║
║ 8   Noa   9       ║
║ 9   Sisi  4       ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```

Now I need a subset based on the data I am searching for.
For instance I'm searching for the record with id 5.
In my result I need more than the record of Jan, I need the two records before Jan and the two records behind Jan too. So I have the following resultset:

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║ id  name  quality ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║ 3   Bill  2       ║
║ 4   Max   1       ║
║ 5   Jan   10      ║
║ 6   Susi  5       ║
║ 7   Chris 6       ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```

Could you give me some keywords for solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the ID field is always in a preset order (two before and two after the specific row can be counted via the ID field), you can do one of two simple queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl1 
WHERE  id BETWEEN 3 AND 7
```

(An SQL Fiddle demo can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/126a4/2))

or:

```
SET @a:=5; 

SELECT * 
FROM   tbl1 
WHERE  id BETWEEN @a - 2 AND @a + 2
```

(An SQL Fiddle demo can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/126a4/7))

I hope this answer your question.
Please let me know if you need anything else.

Good luck!

Comment: Curious question Gidil.  Why did you use ":=" to set instead of "="?

Comment: Just out of habit I guess. Either way is fine as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

```
SET @search_id = 5;

SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE id BETWEEN (@search_id - 2) AND (@search_id + 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL fiddle demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b156a/15

```
(SELECT * FROM test
    WHERE id >= 5
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 3)

UNION 

(SELECT * FROM test
WHERE id < 5
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: Thx a lot. Works as expected. But I prefer the solution from Gidil.